# Cookies в curl (HttpOnly)

Tags: curl, cookie

В файле для cookie, curl создает печеньку с префиксом #HttpOnly_.

Решетка в начале строки навевает мысль о том, что, что она закомментирована и при запросе кукисов из данного файла просто игнорируется. Как быть?

Кука эта - sessid.

*ps. Не вижу причин для закрытия вопроса. Если они есть, дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на справку.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Простите, нашел ответ на StackOverflow - [Curl cookiejar line commented out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11261069/curl-cookiejar-line-commented-out).

PS. все-таки куки с этим префиксом игнорились. Удаление префикса из файла решило проблему.